# Why does pacman stop when I freeze the output with ctrl+s

Tags: arch-linux, signals, pacman

I sometimes use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to send an `XOFF` signal to freeze the output of a program without stopping the program itself. However, *[pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)*, unlike most other programs, stops as if you had pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. It continues as normal upon pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> (`XON`).

Why is this?